# Nome do input type radio com formControlName

Tags: angular, angular-7

Boa noite.

Criei um component para um template padronizado e estou tendo dificuldades para ajustar o nome do input radio fazendo com que apenas um seja selecionado e não todos.

**tema-thumbnail.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'tema-thumbnail',
  templateUrl: './tema-thumbnail.component.html'
})
export class TemaThumbnailComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() tema: Tema
  @Input() parent: FormGroup
  @Input() fcName: string

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**tema-thumbnail.component.html**

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-2" [formGroup]="parent">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" [formControlName]="fcName" [value]="tema.id" >
        <figure>
            <img src="{{tema.url}}" alt="{{tema.titulo}}">
            <figcaption>
                <h4>{{tema.titulo}}</h4>
                <p>{{tema.descricao}}</p>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </label>
</div>
```

E estou utilizando assim:

**evento-informacoes.component.ts**

```
export class EventoInformacoesComponent extends Form implements OnInit {

    temas: Tema[]
    ...
    ...

    ngOnInit() {
      this.temas = this.eventoService.obterTemasDisponiveis()
    }

    ...
    ...

    this.formBuilder.group({
      ...
      'codigo_template': this.formBuilder.control('',Validators.required])
    })

    ...
    ...
}
```

**evento-informacoes.component.html**

```
<form role="form" [formGroup]="form">
...
...

    <div class="row radio">
      <tema-thumbnail *ngFor="let tema of temas" [tema]="tema" [parent]="form" [fcName]="'codigo_template'"></tema-thumbnail>
    </div>

...
...
</form>
```

Porém não estou conseguindo fazer com que o input radio selecione apenas uma opção. Esta sendo possível selecionar várias opções.

O input gerado está sem o "name". Contém apenas **"ng-reflect-name"**

```
<input type="radio" ng-reflect-form-control-name="codigo_template" ng-reflect-value="1" ng-reflect-name="codigo_template" class="ng-dirty ng-valid ng-touched">
```

Comment: pq ta sem o name???

Comment: Colocando o name (no template mesmo para teste. Em **tema-thumbnail.component.html**  <input type="radio" [formControlName]="fcName" [value]="tema.id" name="optTema"> ) recebo o erro.

**ERROR Error: 
      If you define both a name and a formControlName attribute on your radio button, their values
      must match. Ex: <input type="radio" formControlName="food" name="food">**

Comment: pq vc não seta o name com o mesmo valor do formControlName como a mensagem de erro sugere?

Comment: Eu tentei mas posso estar fazendo algo errado. Tentei assim: **<input type="radio" [formControlName]="fcName" [value]="tema.id" name="fcName">** e recebo o mesmo erro. Tentei assim: **<input type="radio" [formControlName]="fcName" [value]="tema.id" [name]="fcName">** e não deu erro. Mas continua o mesmo problema. Seleciono vários e não apenas um.

Comment: Continuando....  E tentei assim: **<input type="radio" [formControlName]="fcName" [value]="tema.id" [name]="name">** onde "name" é um **@input()** name e na chamado faço **<tema-thumbnail *ngFor="let tema of temas" [tema]="tema" [parent]="form" [fcName]="'codigo_template'" [name]="'codigo_template'"></tema-thumbnail>**. Não recebo erro mas seleciono varios e nao apenas um. O mesmo para **<tema-thumbnail *ngFor="let tema of temas" [tema]="tema" [parent]="form" [fcName]="'codigo_template'" [name]="codigo_template"></tema-thumbnail>**  sem ' ' no nome.

Answer (score 0):

Olha, o rádio button precisa ter um `name` igual em todos os radio buttons para que só um deles seja selecionável. Então, tenta usar o `name`ao invés do `ng-reflect-form-control-name`.

Exemplo:

```html
<input (change)="onSelectMovimentacao(1)" class="form-check-inline ml-2" type="radio" name="movimentacao"> Entrada
<input (change)="onSelectMovimentacao(2)" class="form-check-inline ml-2" type="radio" name="movimentacao" [checked]="true"> Saída
```

Eu não consegui pegar o valor do radio button selecionado pelo formControlName, no exemplo acima, como é apenas uma opção de escolha, eu usei o `(change)` para enviar o valor. Para pegar o valor, eu usei o `document` no `component`, para quando uso um `ngFor`.

```js
const auxPerm:any = document.querySelectorAll('input[class="form-check-inline ml-2 perm"]:checked');
```

Qualquer coisa, explica mais nos comentários.

Comment: Quando coloco um name recebo erro. Coloquei o name no template do componente <input type="radio" [formControlName]="fcName" [value]="tema.id" name="optTema">. Recebo o erro **ERROR Error: 
      If you define both a name and a formControlName attribute on your radio button, their values
      must match. Ex: <input type="radio" formControlName="food" name="food">**

Quanto **ng-reflect-form-control-name** nao sou eu quem coloco.... é colocado em tempo de execução

Comment: Já tentou tirar o `formNameControl`e deixar só o `name`? Pois eu faço uma "gambia" para pegar o valor dos input.

Comment: Vi que você está usando colchetes "[]" nas palavras dentro do input, poderia explciar o que cada um deles faz no seu input? Quem sabe podemos mudar essa parte e fazer funcionar

Comment: Claro! Estou seguindo isso https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax . Posso estar errando em algo. Na minha postagem inicial vc pode perceber que cada um dos [ ] é um @Input() ....